# How to use PolynomialSplineFunction from Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, math, polynomial-math, spline, apache-commons-math

I do not understand number two:

> The value of the polynomial spline function for an argument x is
>   computed as follows:
>
> 1. The knot array is searched to find the segment to which x belongs. If x is less than the smallest knot point or greater than the largest
>      one, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.
> 2. Let j be the index of the largest knot point that is less than or equal to x. The value returned is polynomials[j](x - knot[j])

The polynomial array is always one value less than the knot array right? So the second section does not always work? Is there a better way to state number 2?

[Link to documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialSplineFunction.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just says that if `x` belongs to the interval `[knot[j], knot[j+1]]`, then the corresponding `y` value will be computed as `polynomials[j](x - knot[j])`. If your `polynomials` array's last index is `n` then the last `knot` interval will be `[knot[n], knot[n+1]]`, meaning the last index of the `knot` array is `n+1` (so 2 will always hold).

Comment: So is the explanation that I got from the Apache docs just very terse? Am I correct in saying that you had to infer your answer?

Comment: I wouldn't say that, but their explanation is definitely like something you might read in a math textbook. They say that `j` is index of the largest knot less than or equal to `x` which is equivalent to saying that `knot[j]` is the left endpoint of the interval `x` falls into. If `knot[j]` is the left endpoint then it follows that `knot[j+1]` must be the right endpoint. This in turn means that the only way that `polynomials[j]` will produce and `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is if `knot[j+1]` does not exist (i.e., `j` is the last index of `knot`) but this is already taken care of by (1).